# Java HashMap key fits to a pattern?

Tags: java, algorithm, hashmap

I have a Map dataset, and I want to iterate through the keys and search for matches.
So I want to find the maps element, where the key fits to this pattern:

```java
    String searchedKey = "A?C"; // ? means it can be any character
    
    Map<String, MyObject> myMap = new HashMap<>();
    myMap.put("ABC", MyObject(1));
    myMap.put("CDF", MyObject(2));
    myMap.put("ADS", MyObject(3));
    
    for (Map.Entry<String,MyObject> entry : myMap.entrySet()) {
        // in this case, I want to find the first element, because it's key fits the searchedKey, where ? can be anything
    }
```

How can I do this?
Thanks!

Comment: String compare with non `?` characters?

Comment: You need to provide more details. How do `??` and `abc` compare? Are they matched? Do the lengths have to be equal? You want an output list of all matched keys or just boolean true or false?

Comment: one `?` means 1 character (any character), but it can't be empty, so there has to be something there in that placec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this to return a list of found MyObjects.  Note I changed `?` to `.` for any character.

```
String searchedKey = "A.C"; // ? means it can be any character

Map<String, MyObject> myMap = new HashMap<>();
myMap.put("ABC", new MyObject(1));
myMap.put("CDF", new MyObject(2));
myMap.put("ARS", new MyObject(3));
myMap.put("VS", new MyObject(4));
myMap.put("AQC", new MyObject(3));
myMap.put("DS", new MyObject(3));
myMap.put("ASC", new MyObject(10));

List<Map.Entry<String,MyObject>> list = myMap.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getKey().matches(searchedKey))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());


list.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints

```
ASC=10
ABC=1
AQC=3
```

The MyObject class

```
class MyObject {
    int val;
    
    public MyObject(int v) {
        this.val = v;
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return val + "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Regex-Patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) that allow to search Strings for matchings of a logical sequence using [String#matches(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)).

[Here is a page](https://regexr.com/) that might help you create and test a regex for your needs. You might also have to construct your pattern flexible during runtime, depending on how your search works.

Tho keep in mind that a HashMap does not keep the order in which the keys were inserted. keySet() does not return them in a fixed order. If you need them ordered, you could use a [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)

Comment: `LinkedHashMap` does not guarantee a sorted order. It only guarantees the keys can be retrieved in the order they were inserted.

Comment: I meant sorted by insertion. Sorted was the wrong choice of word there :D Just meant that if the insertion order matters for him and he has two entries that match his search criteria, with a normal HashMap he might end up with different results for the same request.